# Simulate "drag & drop" with Windows

Tags: windows, object, arguments, drag

How i can simulate "drag & drop" file with Windows Arguments on "object line" [Object line in red rectangle (image example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ8tS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut properties dialog does not support drag & drop (neither files nor text as far as I can tell).

You could use [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) to change the text but just modifying the shortcut .lnk file is a better option.

From a scripting language you can [set TargetPath and Arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/244677/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-with-the-windows-script-host) on a [WshShortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/xk6kst2k(v=vs.84).aspx) object or use the [IShellLink interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx) in a real application.